# How do I debug a .NET Core MVC application crash on Ubuntu?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-core, crash, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core MVC application (running on Raspberry Pi 3b Raspbian Jesse) that crashes daily. Its under similar load running the same operations throughout the day and night, so its quite hard to determine what causes it to crash.

The application makes good use of `try catch` statements and logging throughout, however, prior to the crash there are no logs of note.

Other than possibly [Raygun](https://raygun.com/platform/crash-reporting), is there a tool one can use to get more information on or after a .NET Core application crash in order to debug? I have seen users make reference to crash dumps in `/var/crash` but cannot determine how to set up this logging

Comment: You could enable an exception handler within the outer most middleware so that it can the dump exception stack when it throws. This approach works if the errors happens within the middleware/mvc/razor page pipeline. If you're looking a remote debug tool, you can take a look at VS/VScode remote debug. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview and https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Attaching-to-remote-processes

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up your .NET Core application to run on Linux as per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1) then debugging an app crash should be relatively simple as per the [View Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1#view-logs) section in the docs

The below presumes your service has been named **kestrel-helloapp.service**

> sudo journalctl -fu kestrel-helloapp.service
>
> For further filtering, time options such as --since today, --until 1
>   hour ago or a combination of these can reduce the amount of entries
>   returned.
>
> sudo journalctl -fu kestrel-helloapp.service --since "2016-10-18" --until "2016-10-18 04:00"